# Outlook Mail replication scenario

Tags: c#, outlook, smtp, pop3

I have a rather intriguing problem I am working on currently. Some backstory:

**Prerequisites:**

The client does not want to pay for the Exchange maintenance and does not have one. And it is rather a lot for a small company with 10 Employees

I can't use IMAP Unfortunately

**The goal**

The Idea is to implement some system where for instance you have 10 computers and each has a mail client with 2 outgoing email addresses (2 Common addresses (aka. info@domain.com, sales@domain.com )) The personal addresses are not of importance in this scenario but they exists

***Objective1:***

The Idea is that all mail clients have subfolders in Outlook for each of the 2 mails where they receive Incoming mails from the 2 accounts.

So far I plan to just prevent outlook from deleting mails younger than 4 months in the account settings.

***Objective2:***

The idea is that all mail clients receive sent mails from the 2 accounts from any client

**The Idea so far**

Here it becomes interesting since there is no straight forward solution that I can think of. So far I am looking into this option:

Create 2 additional mail accounts (info_sent@domain.com  and sales_sent@domain.com  ) and then create an outlook add-in that will when mails are send from one of the 2 accounts automatically attach the respective sent account as a Bcc. Then I can create a rule in outlook that will move the mails that are received from the 2 sent accounts into the respective send subfolders.

I know it is something maybe not worth the effort but I just need to present some sort of alternative to exchange.

**The question**

The question is if anyone maybe was doing something similar in the past or if anyone can think of a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give them a quote for the work which is more than the cost of the exchange licence, and recommend they get that instead.